# Conditional on select dropdown field type not working

Tags: conditionals, drop-down

I have a select dropdown field with 2 values "yes" and "no".
I want to display an entry when the "yes" is selected. Ive done this many times before but now I can't get it to go. It shows just one entry.

If I remove **limit="4"** it works??? If set **limit="8"** it works???

my code looks like this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" status="open" limit="4" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks" dynamic="no" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
    {if dropdown == "yes"}
        {title}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know, it will increase the speed if you don't put an if condition there and use EE `search:CUSTOM_FIELD` parameter in `exp:channel:entries` loop.

Use this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" status="open" limit="4" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks" dynamic="no" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes" search:dropdown="yes"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Also FYI, `limit` parameter will work with `search:CUSTOM_FIELD` and will not work with your `if` condition.

Comment: Hi Mufi, Thanks so much for your fast reply and solution to my problem.